# What does "real dull" refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Sidney speaks to Rita:

> Sidney: Don't tell me you've been playing around with Leo Bartha.
>
> Rita: No, that's what I mean. I'm bein' fired for what I didn't do. He
> came in last week on a **real dull**, rainy night.

What does "real dull" refer to?

Comment: It refers to the ***rainy night***. Stereotypically for *children*, it's *rainy **Sunday afternoons*** that are real[ly] dull and boring (because they're stuck indoors, and can't go out to play).

Comment: 'Real' can be a US variant of 'really'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Real dull", emphasized in this specific way, might be a plot device that is capable of evoking specific motivations or behaviours from the characters in the story.

In this context it means an abso-f*cking-lutely boring, unpleasant, suppressive, humid, cold, gray night, the kind where going outside is the very last thing one would want to do.

Such a night renders the outside world practically non-existent. It limits the boundaries of one's perception to the warm and lit and comfy indoors. There is nothing on the other side of the door and windows worth acknowledging or thinking about.

> He came in last week on a real dull, rainy night.

And in such conditions appears this person in the warm and cozy and very much habitable indoors.

Since the outside world is rendered non-existent, all the more attention is freed up to percieve what's indoors.

Whoever got stuck in such circumstances with each other, got granted an environment where they ended up being able to percieve each other with laser focus.

What they did in that situation or what they did not, is probably part of the plot of the literature you are quoting from...